# How to install Veyon Client

Tags: shutdown, network-monitoring

With the need of shutting down all 34 computers from one place, I installed Veyon Master on the host computer. Now I can't connect the other clients to the host. Any Ideas? Maybe I need to install some client key or something else? Thanks :)

Comment: I have no idea about Veyon but if it's just shutting down the computers why don't you use ssh?

Comment: Actually the real use of the Veyon service is monitoring all the computers from one place including shitting down, remote acces, remote controll, send message.. A practical application for every classroom with many compiters.

Comment: Well... if it's only about shutting down computers remotely, Veyon is probably overkill and ssh with a shell script more than enough. Have you asked in the Veyon Forum?